# iPad Launch image landscape

Tags: xcode, ipad

I keep getting a warning that my ipad launch image landscape isnt 1024x748, while it actually is that size. When i do compile with the 'wrong' size, it gives me a bloated portrait image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Xcode 4.0.2+ then the landscape iPad launch image needs to be 748 * 1024. This is how it works in one of my apps.

Good luck!

Comment: THIS ACTUALLY WORKED! Incredible! Thanks alot! I love you. This is the first time i read this solution.

Comment: Anyway, now it just displays the landscape launch image, even when launching from portrait.

Comment: My filenames are as follows: Default-Landscape~ipad.png (748 * 1024) & Default-Portrait~ipad.png (768 * 1004). Are you setting these manually or on the summary tab of your Xcode project -> launch images? What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Im setting them on my summary tab. I have the latest version (yesterday) of xcode for Snow leopard, 4.0.2. My images are your size too. With the same filenames as in your project by the way.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? Go to Product -> Clean. Also, if this still doesn't work, delete the app from your iPad and rebuild and redeploy it to the device.

Comment: That's become a habit for me, cleaning and redeploying. To no avail in this case.

Comment: But how about deleting the app and re-installing?

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, it still launches with just landscape.

Comment: @Luke let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2662/discussion-between-maikels-and-luke)

Answer (score 1):

@MaikelS - What version of Xcode are you using?

In Xcode 4.0 on Snow Leopard my landscape launch image would throw a warning even though it would load in the app just fine. The warning was actually a triangular yellow caution image superimposed over the landscape launch image (in Xcode select your Project, then select the Target, the select Summary tab and scroll to see launch images).

FWIW, I've since moved to Xcode 4.1 on Lion and the warning has disappeared.

Comment: I updated xCode just yesterday, im on snow leopard. It doesnt load fine in the app either.

Comment: Can you post the image? I'll drop it into one of my projects and see if I can reproduce the warning and behavior.