# Xcode 4 and iPad2 splash screen issue

Tags: xcode, ipad, xcode4, ios4, ipad-2

Thank you for reading this.

I created a brand new project in Xcode 4 (Window based kind) and tried to get the splash screens working.
If I click on the blue icon of my project (top of the project hierarchy)  and then click on "Target/Project", I see that I can drag and drop two launch images to use them as splash screens.
My portrait picture is a 768 x 1004 px png file and my landscape picture is a 1024 x 748 png file.
When I drop the portrait picture, everything looks fine but when I do the same with the landscape picture, I have a big yellow exclamation point that appears.
If I hover my mouse pointer long enough on the exclamation point, it says:"

> the size of the launch image for iPad in landscape mode does not match
>   the recommended size of 1024 x 748 pixels

".
Just to be sure, I verified in Photoshop and a mac buit-in application and both do say my image is a png file of 1024 x 748.
I tried another picture and got the same message. I created a new Xcode project and also got the same message. 
When I build and run the minimalistic project in the iPad simulator, I get the portrait splash vertically in Portrait orientation (ok) and the portrait splash horizontally in Landscape mode (not ok).
What can I do?

Just for you to know:
When I go to the Project-Info.plist, I do see "Supported Interface Orientations (iPad)" and it has 4 items:

- Portrait  (Bottom home button)
- Portrait  (top home button)
- Landscape (left home button)
- Landscape (right home button)

I also copied manually the 5 following files at the root of the project but it didn't help

- Default-Landscape~ipad.png
- Default-Portrait~ipad.png
- Default-LandscapeLeft~ipad.png
- Default-LandscapeRight~ipad.png
- Default-PortraitUpsideDown~ipad.png

Whatever I do, it just recognizes the portrait picture and uses them for each orientation...

At this point, my project is very minimal and is just made of an appDelegate "h" and "m" file and a "mainWindow.xib" file, that's it (I didn't edit any of them yet).

Any clue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:  try making the image **748x1024** instead of *1024x748* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108726/ipad-launch-image-landscape).

From SO question - [iPad Launch image landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108726/ipad-launch-image-landscape):

> If you're on Xcode 4.0.2+ then the landscape iPad launch image needs
>   to be 748 * 1024. This is how it works in one of my apps.

---

Also, Upgrading to xcode 4.1 will fix the big yellow warning you get even when an image is the correct size.

---

The warning is also different based on your plist setting for "Status Bar is initially hidden" or not.  If it's hidden, then it needs to be 1024x768, it not hidden then 1024x748... etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First of all, I got Xcode 4.0 and tried to update it to 4.1 but this one only eligible with OSX Lion which I can't install (all my Mac App are not compatible with Lion yet). So I tried your other solution by creating a landscape picture which is "748*1024" and it still doesn't work. I also created a brand new project and put only the landscape picture with the new format and it didn't work. The only improvement is that with the size you recommend, I don't see the exclamation point anymore but it still doesn't load.

Comment: Does it work if you have just one image named 'Default-Landscape~ipad.png' instead of one for each type of landscape ('Default-LandscapeLeft~ipad.png' and 'Default-LandscapeRight~ipad.png')

Comment: No it doesn't. If I use both of them, I get the portrait splash for all orientations and if I only put the landscape picture (748*1024 or 1024*748, whatever), i get nothing at all (black opening).

Comment: Is the _Default-Landscape~ipad.png_ file listed under the "Copy Bundle Resources" of the "Build Phases" tab (in project settings)?

Comment: Yes it is referenced there and it still doesn't work. I know it's not something I did wrong as the testing projects I use are freshly generated and untouched. (thank you for your help, much appreciated).

Comment: Are you trying this on the simulator or a device?  If its on an actual iPad double check thatyou havent locked the device orientation (the button on the top right above the volume).

Comment: No, just the simulator, that's it.

Comment: Try the following: Go in Finder -> Browse your Project.xcodeproj-File -> Right-(Control) click the file -> Browse contents. Then locate the .xcworkspace file and delete this file. Next time you launch Xcode, the Workspace is generated from scratch. It can sometimes happen, that the workspace-xml is messed up, holding some "old" defaulsImage settings. This once or twice solved my problem with DefaultImages.

Comment: am having the same problem.. mine is weirder.. i add the 4 images for landscape left and right (for ipad retina also) and only one image is loaded (the Right one) regardless of the orientation

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru Make sure in your `Info.plist` you have the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` (right click -> Show Raw Keys/Values) array and that it lists all the orientations you want: `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`, `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`, `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`, `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`.